# Flink: How to set System Properties in TaskManager?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have some code reading message from kafka like below:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "someValue")
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val consumerProperties = new Properties()
    consumerProperties.setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
    consumerProperties.setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
    val kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer011[ObjectNode](consumerProperties.getProperty("topic"), new JsonNodeDeserializationSchema, consumerProperties)

    val stream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)
}
```

When the source try to read message from Apache Kafka, org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.defaultContext function will load "java.security.auth.login.config" property.

But the property is only set in JobManager, and when my job get running, the property can not load correctly in TaskManager, so the source will fail.

I tried to set extra JVM_OPTS like "-Dxxx=yyy", but the flink cluster is deployed in standalone mode, environment variable can not be changed very often.

Is there any way to set property in TaskManager?

Comment: do you mean these properties https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#taskmanager?

Answer (score 1):

The file `bin/config.sh` of Flink standalone cluster holds a property named `DEFAULT_ENV_JAVA_OPTS`.

Also if you `export $JVM_ARGS="your parameters"` the file `bin/config.sh` will load it using these lines:

```
# Arguments for the JVM. Used for job and task manager JVMs.
# DO NOT USE FOR MEMORY SETTINGS! Use conf/flink-conf.yaml with keys
# KEY_JOBM_MEM_SIZE and KEY_TASKM_MEM_SIZE for that!
if [ -z "${JVM_ARGS}" ]; then
    JVM_ARGS=""
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to set the properties per job, not the whole cluster.

Comment: I guess this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977287/flink-how-to-pass-extra-jvm-options-to-taskmanager-and-jobmanager